# What to do with dynamic url after rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

After you've been able to successfully create a url rewrite how do you handle the original and other possibly ways to access a page. This of course to prevent duplicate content. For example if I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^blog/(\d+)/([\w\-/\.]+)/?$ blog.php?id=$1&article_title=$2 [L]
```

I'm able to access the page by the url

> https://www.mysite.com/blog/10/mysite.com (the mysite.com is the article title)

The problem is I'm also able to access the site by going to

> https://www.mysite.com/blog.php?id=10article_title=sitetitle
>
> https://www.mysite.com/blog.php?id=10
>
> ect.

How are you supposed to handle those particular urls.

Also should I change the blog.php?id=10 to the rewritten url? Can I rely on something else and just start using the full rewritten url now? The site is new.

Answer (score 0):

For my web site, I have the script that gets called from inside the rewrite detect the URI they were fetched from (using the "REQUEST_URI" variable that at least Apache sets), and redirect to the canonical one if they ever get called with the internal one (outputting a 301 direction).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is this a blanket approach so i don't have to manually 301 each individual url? How do you do this approach?

Comment: Are you referring to query strings?

Comment: I check the value of the REQUEST_URI variable (that Apace set up). If it contains "?variable=parameter", I let the script respond with a 301 status code, pointing to the URL I want to have visible.